# The type or name "KnownSourceValueInjection" could not be found

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

I Would like to know why is this method found as an answer on many questions here not working, there are errors in "KnownSourceValueInjection". Also "GetByName(...)"is not working, it says: "propertyinfo[]" does not contain a definition for "GetByName" accepting a first argument of type "propertyinfo[]" could be found.I'm working on a web service.
I'm using:

- using Omu.ValueInjecter;
- using Omu.ValueInjecter.Utils;
- using Omu.ValueInjecter.Injections;

This is the method.

```
    public class ReaderInjection : KnownSourceValueInjection<IDataReader>
    {
        protected override void Inject(IDataReader source, object target)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < source.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var activeTarget = target.GetProps().GetByName(source.GetName(i), true);
                if (activeTarget == null) continue;

                var value = source.GetValue(i);
                if (value == DBNull.Value) continue;

                activeTarget.SetValue(target, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use KnownSourceInjection, it was renamed in the new version; and for the ReaderInjection see the source [here](https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter/blob/8fc0d08c7323ec8e275fbb88448e9515ee3178b6/Samples/DALSample/ReaderInjection.cs)

```
public class ReaderInjection : KnownSourceInjection<IDataReader>
{
    protected override void Inject(IDataReader source, object target)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < source.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var trgProp = target.GetType().GetProperty(source.GetName(i), BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (trgProp == null) continue;

            var value = source.GetValue(i);
            if (value == DBNull.Value) continue;

            trgProp.SetValue(target, value);
        }
    }
}
```